# Change Liferay 6.1.2 logfile location

Tags: liferay, config, logfiles

Does anyone know how I can tell liferay to put its logfile in a location of my choise? Currently all log files are stored in ~/logs. I'd rather hav them in /usr/jboss/liferay/logs due to file system storage limitation.

Thanks for your help and regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

Found it. Set `liferay.home` in `portal-ext.properties` to avoid `default-location` in users home.